# Android App Crashes When Sending Data To Server

Tags: java, networking, android-emulator, android

I am trying to send some data to my server which is publicly available on the internet.
The app gets started as a service after boot is completed (permission is added), how ever the app crashes.
I have narrowed the code down.
It seems like it crashes when it is trying to send data to the server.

Below is my code.
I really appreciate if you guys can help me on this.

```
package com.example.bootstart;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

class SendData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {


    public void sendinfo(){
            // Creating HTTP client
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // Creating HTTP Post
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.mydomain.com/controller_name/funtion_name");

        // Building post parameters
        // key and value pair
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("imei", "12345"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("welawa", "12315646545"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", "123.25"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", "52.22323"));

        // Url Encoding the POST parameters
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }




}
```

I am a php developer, trying to write a simple app that logs GPS cordinates.

I can't check the console because some thing has made the emulator working. I always get the emulator-arm.exe has stopped working bla bla bla. So I use my phone and restart it everytime when I test. So unfortunately I do not have access to a log either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `sendinfo()` called?

Comment: where you are checking Internet connection before calling `sendinfo()` method ?

Comment: If you are not having log then generate `Toast` with exception message.

Comment: call sendInfo() from doInbackground()

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thank you for the tip. Definitely will add this when I get the basics covered. I just made sure that the internet connectivity is there by connecting the phone to a wifi for the testing.

Comment: sendinfo() is called from another class by using SendData  sending= new SendData();sending.sendinfo();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where is `sendinfo()` called? But I think in your main **Activity** you call that:

`new SendData().sendInfo();` :(

Please put sendInfo to **doInBackground**

And in your **Activity**: `new SendData().execute();`

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you I do not get the error now. However, the log says "Network" under Tag in console. I do not receive any data to my server. I am pretty confident on the server coding. I have made it to email me every time the page is requested (just so I know that it is being called), but it doesn't get called. Can you see if there is any thing wrong? I use new SendData().execute(); to call the class from another service. The coding hasn't changed from the above. Any help?

Comment: So, I think we need more time to talk about this, please move this comment to chat. I think, I can help you resolve this problem.

Comment: On another note, in the phone normally you can see the 3g icons light in green and orange. But it doesn't seem to be happening even though the log says "Network".

Comment: Hi, a newbie in stackoverflow. Would this help? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46214/android-issue-in-network

Comment: It's so difficult to talk about this problem. What kind of error with Network? There are many problem around it.